# How do I install the optional channel for RHEL to install Puppet?

Tags: linux, installation, puppet, redhat

I'm trying to install Puppet on RedHat Linux Version 7.

The instructions say you need to install an "optional channel".

Can someone provide directions on how to do this?  I want to install Puppet. I tried to install Puppet Master without the optional channel.  The main thing that is wrong is that I cannot start puppetmaster.

When I try and run:

```
/etc/init.d/puppetmaster restart
```

But I get this:

```
-bash: /etc/init.d/puppetmaster: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Propulsion, you'll probably get better answers over on ServerFault, but you can find more information about managing subscriptions over here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1/html-single/Quick_Registration_for_RHEL/index.html

Comment: Specifically what OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

From reading over the docs:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

(From the [RedHat Docs](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/265523))

Then, to install Puppetserver:

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install puppet-server
```

From the [Puppet Docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_el.html)

That should work.

Comment: I just noticed the link that tells you how to to enable optional is 404'd in the Puppet Docs! I just opened a PR to fix it :) https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-docs/pull/464

Comment: I tried this: subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms  I got this:
Error: rhel-7-server-optional-rpms is not a valid repo ID. Use --list option to see valid repos.

Comment: I'm getting following error when I enable rhel-7-repo
Error: rhel-7-server-optional-rpms is not a valid repo ID. Use --list option to see valid repos.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I install the release package of the repository, the Puppet repository in this particular example:

```
BASEARCH=$(uname -i);
RELEASE=$(cat /etc/redhat-release | sed -rn '/(Final|release)/s/^[^0-9]*|[^0-9.]*$//gp' | sed -e 's/[.].*//');

rpm -Uhv http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/$RELEASE/products/$BASEARCH/$(curl -s http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/$RELEASE/products/$BASEARCH/ | grep puppetlabs-release | tail -n1 | sed 's%.*>\(.*.release-.*noarch.rpm\)<.*%\1%');
```

This code installs the latest version of the release package for the OS version you are running on. You do not need to know the precise release number...

Than install the Puppet server

```
yum install puppet-server
```